# Android FAB Animation when new Activity starts or Resume to previous Activity

Tags: android, animation, material-design, floating-action-button

I want to animate my **FAB (Floating Action Button)**.

My goal is presented in this youtube video:
[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hiPjxi2oKoo&index=4&list=WL)

Does anybody know how I can **animate** my *FAB* and how will look like the animation in the `xml` file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void hideView(final View view) {
    view.animate()
            .translationY(view.getHeight()+YOUR MARGIN)
            .setDuration(300)
            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                }
            });
}

public void showView(final View view) {
    view.animate()
            .translationY(0)
            .setDuration(300)
            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                }
            });
}
```

**EDITED:**

for i sec wait call it from :

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            showView(...)
        }
    }, 1000);
```

you might have to use runOnUiThread(new Runnable(...)) inside run

**Re Edit:**

```
public void hideView(final View view) {
view.animate()
        .translationY(-10)
        .setDuration(30)
        .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                view.animate()
                  .translationY(view.getHeight()+YOUR MARGIN + 10)
                  .setDuration(300)
                  .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                  @Override
                  public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                      super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                  }
              });
            }
        });
```

}

Comment: add showView(...) in onResume(..) and hideView(...) in onClick or whatever triggers the intent

Comment: you will have to call hideView in order to see translation

Comment: How can I get the effect, that the FAB wait a second and then goes down? Like in this youtube video?

Comment: unfortunately not :-( The problem is that the FAB is shown in the previous and following activity in the tutorial...

Comment: all you have to do is call the methods in right ways, can you explain what is it you are getting currently?..and whats the difference?

Comment: EDIT

I have put the "startActivity" in the onAnimationEnd Method. Now the Animation animate completely. But how can I set the FAB a little bit higher and then it goes down?

Comment: call two animations start by lifting it a little up then call the other on in onAnimationEnd()

Comment: you will have to play with the values of offset and time to get the exact effect, bt this code should do the trick